# Merge numpy arrays/dataframe with same values and keep difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays.

The first looks like this:

```
        Date          Price  Volume
2019-04-15 01:00:00    50      100
2019-04-15 02:00:00    35      120
```

The second array looks like this:

```
        Date          Price  Volume
2019-04-15 01:00:00    50      200
2019-04-15 02:00:00    40      130
```

The output array should look like:

```
        Date          Price  Volume
2019-04-15 01:00:00    50      300
2019-04-15 02:00:00    35      120
2019-04-15 02:00:00    40      130
```

Because the prices and the date of the first row are the same, I sum the volumes in the output array.

I've tried several methods. Maybe someone has an idea how to create the output array or dataframe.

Comment: Can we assume you mean `dataframe` instead of `array`?

Comment: What happens if you have the same date but different price?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate sum with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by both columns:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['Date','Price'], as_index=False)['Volume'].sum()
print (df)
                  Date  Price  Volume
0  2019-04-15 01:00:00     50     300
1  2019-04-15 02:00:00     35     120
2  2019-04-15 02:00:00     40     130
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df=pd.merge(df1, df2,'outer', on=['Date','Price'])
df['Volume']=df[['Volume_x','Volume_y']].sum(axis=1)
df=df.drop(columns=['Volume_x','Volume_y'])
```